# Spyder 4 Plots Pane Not Displaying

Tags: python, spyder

using Spyder 4 which is no longer displaying the Plots pane above the console. I have ensured that the backend is set to Inline but the pane still does not show up.

[image: Code]

[image: Console]

[image: Settings]

If anyone knows any solutions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All panes are available in the menu `View > Panes`. And please don't open a new question for something like this. You could have added a comment in your previous one.

Comment: Thank you, I apologize for the spam and easy questions.

Comment: No worries, I'm just giving you some advice for you to keep using Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to go to the menu `View > Panes` and activate the entry corresponding to the Plots pane.