# I can't see plot in the console

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have a problem with spyder. I can't see the plot that I produce in the console. I know that it should be a 'Plots' fold. But I can't find it. Do you know how to solve the problem? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287237/spyder-4-plots-pane-not-displaying/60531400#60531400).

Comment: Please someone upvote my answer so we can mark this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spyder 4 Plots Pane Not Displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287237/spyder-4-plots-pane-not-displaying)

Comment: @CarlosCordoba You can vote-to-close this as a duplicate of the question with your answer.

Comment: yes The answer is in your post. Thanks and sorry for the easy question. Plots still open in other pages. What can I do in order to watch them in the "plots" folder? Thanks

Comment: @GinoMempin, thanks for your help!

Comment: @GabrieleValvo, no worries about the easy question. To show your plots in the Plots pane, you need to go to `Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Backend` and select the `Inline` entry there. After that, please close and start Spyder again.